# How to echo an external page from your domain

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, proxy, same-origin-policy

When I embed an external `HTTP` iframe into my `HTTPS` page, I get a mixed content error message:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/"></iframe>
```

To work around this limitation I'd like to echo the external page from my own domain. How should I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `http` page with `curl` (or any other lib), and print out the reponse into some `div` (this `div` will be instead of the `iframe`).

Please attach your `PHP` page (who contains the `iframe`), if you want more direction...

proxy.php

```
<?php
    $url = "http://url-of-iframe/";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = print curl_exec($ch);

    //in case that the page does not contains the <base> tag, then add it
    $base = '<base href="http://www.base-of-iframe.com/" /><!--[if IE]></base><![endif]-->';
    $response = str_replace("<head>", "<head>".$base, $response);
?>
```

page.html

```
 <html><iframe src="https://www.yourServer.com/proxy.php"></iframe></html>
```

**You must be sure that `"http://url-of-iframe/"` is a trusted site! otherwise, he can load malicious content into your page!**

Comment: `iframe` has much more different functionality and purpose than `div`.

Comment: All of the functionality can be implemented on his request with `curl`. This is the way to do a proxy, not such?

Comment: I am speaking about client-side. Proxy does not really care about how request was made at transportation layer (i.e. requested by iframe or ajax).

Comment: You can find any funct. (without cookies) that there is a difference between iframe and based-proxy-div? (indeed, user's cookies cannot be taken but hi, such is a proxy...)

Comment: @MeNa: I haven't created the `PHP` page and that's what I'm asking for help.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but doesn't it break the layout when the target page has non-absolute URLs and relative links?

Comment: Something like this `http://url-of-iframe?a=1&b=2`? there is no problem. Check and let me know..

Comment: Ah, you right! see my updated answer. NOTE: in case you prefer use div instead iframe, you will need different solution, based on reg.-ex. that replace all the URL's.

Comment: Great! One more question, please: how can I create the `base href` automatically out of `$url` value?

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't understand .. can you explain more please?

Comment: The iframe URL `$url = "http://url-of-iframe/"` is not fixed and can dynamically change, so the base URL should change automatically.

Comment: You mean that `proxy.php` is dynamically? he can serve various url's? if so, how do you determine which page he will serve at given time? in same way you can determine the base in `<base>` tag...